# Laravel and mailgun set up correctly, but wont send email

Tags: php, laravel, mailgun

I am trying to get my emails to work from Laravel using mailgun. However, I have hit a brick wall.
I have set up my everything as per the documents. All config, env everything is good.

I followed this example (of many).
https://enlear.academy/using-mailgun-to-send-emails-from-laravel-framework-9d5a39ba946a

So far, mailgun shows DNS is good after verification

[image]

Next I do     `'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'mailgun'),` in the config/mail.php file

Then I do the below in config/services.php

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'),
    ],
```

And finally in my .env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/website.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=reallysupersecretkeygoeshere
MAIL_PORT=587
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net
```

That should do it, but for some reason no success?!?

So I looked at the guzzle to see what is going on, to see if its even sending.
Like the pic below and I get a 200 success value, so its sending it off.
[image]

I went even further and did it with curl just to double check

```
 $from = 'Testemail';
        $to = 'someemail@bla.com';
        $cc = 'Member Placement';
        $bcc = 'Member Placement';
        $subject = 'Member Team Placement';
        $message = '<b>Member Team Placement</b> .';

        $mailgunsecret = 'secretcode';
        $mailguurl = 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/a.website.com';
        var_dump($mailguurl);
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:'.$mailgunsecret);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $mailguurl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            array('from' => $from,'to' => $to, 'cc' => $cc, 'bcc' => $bcc, 'subject' => $subject, 'html' => $message));

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        var_dump($response);
```

And I get **"Mailgun Magnificent API"** which is great, but no email gets sent which is not really magnificent.

So its failing on their end. What could I possibly have missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is slightly embarrassing. Make sure you do below consistently. (Late nights, but still does not explain the hardcoded part)

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

Mailgun support was helpful and had to find out via them that there was a typo.
Might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

You have setup two different mailgun endpoints.

Check:

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN'),
        'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('MAILGUN_ENDPOINT', 'api.mailgun.net'), <-- Here
    ],
```

and

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/website.com
MAILGUN_SECRET=reallysupersecretkeygoeshere
MAIL_PORT=587
MAILGUN_ENDPOINT=api.eu.mailgun.net <-- here
```

Comment: At your first Here, the second property is default should the  MAILGUN_ENDPOINT be missing from the .env? I have hardcoded it in the curl. With and without the eu in the endpoint. Just to be sure :)

Comment: @Sprep well, considering the fact that some people have experienced issues with the `eu` endpoint by not adding it (including myself), it might be possible that its the cause of you not receiving the emails. In other projects I went with the US and didn't have to specify it. That's why I pointed out the difference in endpoints (should be the same, if I'm not mistaken).

Comment: You made me look closer at this. The issue it seems, is that I did not run all the cache clearing properly. Thanks for making me look at this closer. Everything was set up correctly.